# Sublime Text 3 right-click context menu is missing many options

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I hadn't updated before this. I did recently try to update and I get the same right-click menu. (Running 3.0 Build 3143)

I used to be able to right-click on a file and duplicate it (among many other things). But now the options on right-click are missing.
Is anyone else experiencing the same thing or know of a fix for this?

[image: Sublime Text Context Menu]

Comment: Core Sublime doesn't include a `Duplicate...` item in the side bar menu, but the [FileManager](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileManager) package adds one (and probably others); are you sure all of your usual packages are installed and not in `ignored_packages`?

Comment: This is the correct answer. I am on a different computer and must have that package installed on my home computer. I just installed the FileManager package and I now get, New, Duplicate, Move, Open in Browser, etc.... Thanks a lot! I was pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 4):

you can install a package called "Side​Bar​Enhancements" from package manager.

That will allow yourself to get those options.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements

or can use "Side​Bar​Tools:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarTools

In sublime, open project manager with Ctrl+Shift+P (on Mac it is ⌘+Shift+P)

type in package you want to install and press Enter

it would take while, and after that you should have some more options to use in sidebar.